# Get the Id from the file uploaded in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the ID of the file that was uploaded. Currently I am using

```
function uploadFiles(data) {

 var arquivo = data.myFile;

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("idFolder");

  var subirArquivo = folder.createFile(arquivo);


  return subirArquivo.getUrl();


  Logger.log(subirArquivo.getId());

}
```

Can someone help telling me what is wrong?

Comment: The log is after the return statement, therefore not reachable. are you sure you are not getting the ID?

Comment: Thank you, it was that.